# Saving selected items in Listbox combined with radio button into new field

Tags: ms-access, listbox

I am trying to combine multiple selection criteria into one new field. This can be a text box or listbox, whatever is handy to work with.

I do not know how to attach a zip file with my access database so I will send a pictures to show my access form.[Access Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8T0G.png)

At the top you are able to filter the database on various criteria and the results will show up in the ListBox beneath. 
Then you are able to choose one of the calculation options or select an item in the Listbox or create your own value. By choosing one of the radio buttons above I clicking the save button I would like the following to happen.

- Columns 0 to 4 from the selected item in the ListBox should be saved in a box underneath.
- The value of the selected option from the radio button should be saved next to it (as column 5)
- Columns 6 to 9 from the selected item in the ListBox should be saved next to it.
- If the user did not select an item in the ListBox there should be a popup that he should select an item.
- The user should be able to perform multiple searches and save all the selected items for each search, so at the end the user has an overview of all the items he has saved.

I hope my question is clear, otherwise just let me know!

Thanks in advance,
Vinesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make a work around by using an append query.
Now it is possible to save the selected item in the listbox combined with the selected option of the radio buttons.
Sadly every time you hit the button you are asked if you agree on making a change in the table and that the rows will be updated.
Is it possible to either turn these two messages off, or to find a direct way of saving the data into the table?

Comment: It is under options. Found it.